# Reset JS timer when window goes out of focus

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Been twisting my head for a long time over this and can't seem to get it to work.

Basically trying to reset the timer when the window goes out of focus for longer than 30 seconds.

I'd be thankful for any solution that works.

Regards, Will.

```
window.onData = function(data) {
        if (data.setDisplay == true) {
            
            $("#container").css('display', 'flex');
            $("body").fadeIn(1000);
            var counter = 90;
    var c = 90;
    var i = setInterval(function(){
    
        $(".loading-page .counter h1").html("YOU HAVE " + c + " SECONDS LEFT UNTIL RESPAWN");
        $(".loading-page .counter hr").css("width", c + "");
      counter--;
      c--;
        
      if(counter == 0) {
        
        $(".loading-page .counter h1").html("YOU MAY DO /RESPAWN");
        $(".loading-page .counter p").html("DON'T FORGET THE NEW LIFE RULE!");
         clearInterval(i);
      }
    }, 1000);
        } else {
            $("#container").css('display', 'none');
            $("body").css('display', 'none');

        }
        
    }


    window.onload = function(e) {
        window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            onData(event.data)
        });
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you would want to use `blur` to initiate the timer? - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus_event

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean this?

Not tested but has enough snippets to be moved around

```js
const onData = function(data) {
  if (data.setDisplay == true) {
    $("#container").css('display', 'flex');
    $("body").fadeIn(1000);
    
    let tId = setInterval(function() {
      $(".loading-page .counter h1").html("YOU HAVE " + counter + " SECONDS LEFT UNTIL RESPAWN");
      $(".loading-page .counter hr").css("width", counter);
      counter--;
      if (counter == 0) {
        $(".loading-page .counter h1").html("YOU MAY DO /RESPAWN");
        $(".loading-page .counter p").html("DON'T FORGET THE NEW LIFE RULE!");
        clearInterval(tId);
      }
      localStorage.setItem("counter",counter);
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    $("#container").hide()
    $("body").hide()
  }
}

let counter;
const getCounter = function() {
  counter = localStorage.getItem("counter");
  counter = counter === null ? 90 : +counter; // continue from where it was
  const now = new Date().getTime()
  const blurred = sessionStorage.getItem("blurred");
  blurred = blurred ? +blurred : 0;
  if (blurred && (now-blurred)/1000) >30) counter = 0;
};
$(function() {
  $(window).on('message', function(event) {
    onData(event.data)
  });
  $(window).on("blur",function() {
     sessionStorage.setItem("blurred",new Date().getTime())
  })
});
$(window).on("focus",getCounter )
```